# Creating and texturing large locations

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, unreal-engine

I'm really sorry if this is very banal question, but i didn't find something i need. Anyway.

I need to create really large building and then export it to Unreal Engine 4. It's really complex system of corridors, rooms etc. So what is the best way to do it?
I have a temptation to do it in one-two-three (limited quantity
) meshes, 'cause it's easy to create, but what about texturing? If i make UV for this large object, details will be too small and i'll need to create very high-resolutioned texture, so i think it's not the best way.

On the other hand, if i create module system where every element of building will be separated mesh (standart section, turn section, intersect section, entrance etc), i'm afraid that it will be hard to texture. Textures can don't match, and seams can be visible (sorry for my English, i really don't know how to explain it correctry, but i hope you understand what i'm talking about :).

What **the best** way to do it? How you solve this problem? I'm not interested in technical details, 'cause i believe i can do it on my own, i just want to ask about way to go.